# Ошибка с созданием PDF файла в android

Tags: java, android, файлы, pdf

Мне в приложении нужно создавать файл с информацией, эту информацию я получаю и отображаю на графике, теперь данные которые я брал для построения графика мне нужно положить в PDF файл, но он не создается на устройстве, хотя в проекте никаких ошибок не показывает

```
public class GraphActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button pdf;
    TextView textView;
    String infoForError;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_graph2);
        Bundle arguments = getIntent().getExtras();
        String date = arguments.getString("Date").toString();//получение даты ошибки
        ArrayList<String> labels=getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("Значения label");//получение лейблов
        ArrayList<Integer> dataErrors=getIntent().getIntegerArrayListExtra("Значения duration");//получ знач durat
        String nameErB=getIntent().getStringExtra("Имя ошибки");//получение имени ошибки
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.append(nameErB);
        BarChart barChart;
        barChart=(BarChart) findViewById(R.id.bargraph);
        ArrayList<BarEntry> barEntries=new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0;i<dataErrors.size();i++){
            barEntries.add(new BarEntry(dataErrors.get(i),i));
        }
        BarDataSet barDataSet=new BarDataSet(barEntries,"Измеряемое значение");
        ArrayList<String> theDates=new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0;i<labels.size();i++){
            theDates.add(labels.get(i));
        }
        infoForError="Название ошибки: "+nameErB+" за "+date+" было найдено "+dataErrors.size()+"ошибок";
        BarData theData=new BarData(theDates,barDataSet);
        barChart.setData(theData);
        barChart.setTouchEnabled(true);
        barChart.setDragEnabled(true);
        barChart.setScaleEnabled(true);
        BarGraphSeries<DataPoint> series=new BarGraphSeries<DataPoint>();

        //pdf=(Button) findViewById(R.id.PDF);
        //pdf.setOnClickListener(this);
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(GraphActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    }
        public void createMyPDF(View view){
            PdfDocument myPdfDocument=new PdfDocument();
            PdfDocument.PageInfo myPageInfo=new PdfDocument.
                    PageInfo.Builder(300,600,1).create();
            PdfDocument.Page myPage=myPdfDocument.startPage(myPageInfo);
             Paint myPaint=new Paint();
             String myString=textView.getText().toString();
             int x=10,y=25;
             myPage.getCanvas().drawText(infoForError,x,y,myPaint);

             myPdfDocument.finishPage(myPage);
             String myFilePath= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/myPDFFile.pdf";
             File myFile=new File(myFilePath);

             try{
                 myPdfDocument.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(myFile));
             }
             catch (Exception e){
                 e.printStackTrace();
                 textView.setText("Ошибка при сохранении в PDF");
             }
             myPdfDocument.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: В вашем коде не видно вызова метода `createMyPDF()`

Comment: он вызывается при нажатии на кнопку на активити

Comment: "он вызывается при нажатии на кнопку на активити" – так покажи как вызывается